# Is it safe to leave baggage in budget hotels Rome?

Tags: luggage, safety, italy, rome

I'll be staying in Italy for almost a week. I've planned to stay at a budget hotel (~40-50 EUR per day) or B&B in **Rome**. I'll visit other cities using train and plan to leave most of my (and partner's) bags in the room and take a small backpack.

It might happen that we end up staying at another city (50% chance for one particular day, looking at the itinerary) and return next morning. Of course we'll keep our valuables and travelling documents etc in hand - but is it a good idea to leave the luggage in the hotel for more than a day?

Comment: Ask them , we can’t be sure here.

Comment: @AliGajani And they will invariably say they can't be responsible for valuables in the room. What the question is concerned with is whether it is practically a big risk to leave them in the room.

Comment: @MJeffryes yes, correct.

Comment: What is safe is a matter of opinion, and the answer surely varies from hotel to hotel. However, Italy is hardly the Wild West and there are many tourists in Rome. It would be surprising if stuff got routinely stolen from hotel rooms.

Comment: @DavidRicherby thanks. That answers it. I've booked room in a quite prestigious international hotel chain